# Error in library(shiny) : there is no package called 'shiny' ON WINDOWS

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I developed a Shiny app that runs fine locally, but I get

> Error in library(shiny) : there is no package called 'shiny'

when I try to publish to shinyapps.io.

I have seen multiple responses about how to correct on Ubuntu, etc., but I am running R 3.2.2 and R Studio 0.99.486 on Windows 7 Enterprise.

How I can correct this problem on Windows?

Comment: How did they correct it on Ubuntu?

Comment: It was all done in the shell. Giving permissions to Shiny user, I believe. But I can't submit the code since it is sudo su.

Comment: I don't understand why this is considered a _Windows_ problem when publishing on _shinyapps.io_?

Answer (score 5):

I've found a solution in shinyapp's issue [#73](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/issues/73). They don't really explain why this happens, but they advise to use `require()` instead.

Both `ui` and `server` objects are functions and `require()` is prefered inside functions. Take a look at `library()`'s documentation:

> library(package) and require(package) both load the namespace of the package with name package and attach it on the search list. require is designed for use inside other functions;

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I will try this with require(), though it used to work without doing so in the past. To my knowledge, I did not update O/S, R/RStudio, etc. when I started encountering this issue.

Comment: This appears to have resolved the issue. Thanks Tomas. Not the best error message, but I am thankful that I am "back in business".

I appreciate everyone's contributions!

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late but maybe someone else will benefit from it later on.

Had same issue on Windows 10.

I just used manual installation:

- Tools -> Install packages -> type your packages and hit install.

Then everything you need will be there for you.

Comment: Thanks Joe, The package is installed. As I mentioned above, this used to work as expected in the past, then "suddenly" I began encountering the error. Not sure exactly what might have changed that caused this new behavior. 

By chance, do you have other thoughts on this?

Thanks!